# Internal point transformed in an external one?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C} $ be an analytic function over a connected open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\gamma$ a rectifiable closed curve in $\Omega$. If $a$ is a point which is in the interior of $\gamma$, can $f(a)$ be outside the region enclosed by the transformed curve $f \circ \gamma$  ?

Comment: Does $f(z)=1/z$ count as an example?

Comment: And exactly what kind of closed curve do you have in mind? Intuitively, I find that with such $f$ it works only with curves rounding the origin (where $f$ is not analytic).

Comment: Any circle centered at the origin will do. The unit circle, for example

Comment: Following the definition of analytic function in $\Omega$, it is required that $f$ has a derivative in each point of $\Omega$. But at the origin $1/z$ is not defined, so it does not have a derivative.

Comment: Indeed in this case $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Probably it is not clear from the question, but I mean that $a$ is a generic point (you can choose any inner point) from the interior region of the curve, so we consider $f$ to be defined and analytic over all inner points. Maybe I'll edit the question.

Comment: In this case the answer is *probably* affirmative but I'm by no means an expert of those things. I can only guess that the answer lies somewhere around the definition of the winding number.

Comment: BTW if you edit your question I will upvote it.